# Failed to deploy on Firebase hosting via Github

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, deployment, hosting

I'm quite new to Firebase hosting and I failed to truly understand how deployment work when you connect your github repository to Firebase.
I'm used to using Render to host my react application and once connected I only need to commit and push to update my application.

However it seems that I made a mistake using Firebase hosting command on my terminal.
First I've follow all steps to connect my Github repo to Firebase hosting and I can see on my Firebase account that it works.

However I tried to make some change on my local repo and then I commit and push my work. I did not create a specific branch to make the change and to merge with main.

I wonder how to solve conflict so that it can merge on the main branch or do I have to reset commit and create a new branch to push and merge on main after ?

Detail info on my commit

```
.firebaserc
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "project"
  }
}
 20 changes: 20 additions & 0 deletions20  
.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-merge.yml
@@ -0,0 +1,20 @@
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT
 }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: project
 17 changes: 17 additions & 0 deletions17  
.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml
@@ -0,0 +1,17 @@
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT }}'
          projectId: project
 16 changes: 16 additions & 0 deletions16  
firebase.json
@@ -0,0 +1,16 @@
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
  2 changes: 1 addition & 1 deletion2  
src/App.css
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@ body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  z-index: 9998;
}
```

z-index: 9999; is highlighted in red
z-index: 9998; is highlighted in green

Detail info on my actions worklow :

```
Run npm ci && npm run build
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's typescript@5.2.2 does not satisfy typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit]
npm ERR! [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-01-21T16_18_26_746Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Thank you in advance